# Using PowerShell script to replace build number in DLL version info

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to PowerShell and it seems like a reasonable way to replace the build number in my DLLs (by modifying the .rc files) with the revision number from my SVN repository.

Using PowerShell ISE, I created the following variables:

```
$1 = "123"
$revision = "230"
```

Now I am testing my string replacement with the following commands to see how it behaves vs. what I have been reading online.  I am expecting to find something that will give me back a file version of `12,3,0,230`:

```
$pattern = '(^\s*FILEVERSION\s*[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,)[0-9]+$'

' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace $pattern, "`$1"
# returns " FILEVERSION 12,3,0,"

' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace $pattern, "$1"
# returns "123"

' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace $pattern, '$1'
# returns " FILEVERSION 12,3,0,"

' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace $pattern, "`$1$revision"
# returns "$1230"

' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace $pattern, "`$1`$revision"
# returns " FILEVERSION 12,3,0,$revision"

' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace $pattern, "$revision`$1"
# returns "230 FILEVERSION 12,3,0,"
```

I am surprised by the results from attempts 4 and 6.  With attempt 4, why is PowerShell not replacing `$revision` with "230"?  Also with attempt 6, why is it getting replaced properly when it comes before `` `$1 ``?  I looked for information about scoping within the replacement string for backticks, and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a replacement operation PowerShell first expands the PowerShell variables before handing the match and replacement strings off to the regular expression engine. Hence the replacement string `` "`$1$revision" `` is expanded to `"$1230"` and passed to the regexp engine. Since there is no 1230th captured group to be expanded the backreference remains as-is.

To avoid this issue put the backreference identifier in curly brackets:

```
'FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace '...', "`${1}$revision"
```

That ensures your replacement string consists of the backreference `$1` and the string `230`.

---

Notes about what the other approaches are doing (for the sake of completeness):

> ```
> ' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace '...', "`$1"
> ```

Returns `" FILEVERSION 12,3,0,"` because the entire match is replaced with the backreference to the first capturing group and nothing else.

> ```
> ' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace '...', "$1"
> ```

Returns `"123"` because PowerShell expands the *variable* `$1` before it's passed to the regexp engine. The latter just sees the string `"123"`.

> ```
> ' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace '...', '$1'
> ```

Same behavior as with the first approach (the single quotes prevent PowerShell from expanding the variable `$1` just like escaping the `$` does).

> ```
> ' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace '...', "`$1`$revision"
> ```

Returns `" FILEVERSION 12,3,0,$revision"` because both `$` are escaped, so PowerShell doesn't expand `$revision`, and for the regexp engine `$revision` is just an ordinary string.

> ```
> ' FILEVERSION 12,3,0,0' -replace '...', "$revision`$1"
> ```

Returns `"230 FILEVERSION 12,3,0,"` because PowerShell expands `$revision`, but this time the value stands before the backreference, so the regexp engine can expand `$1` to the first captured group.

Comment: Thank you!!!  That did the trick.  And now I understand the expansion better, and totally makes sense.